# Insert variable to query builder of Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, fields-attributes

I have a variable to input to query builder in feature class to feature class arcpy's tool. It doesn't work even I think it is already correct on my script.

The script is like below:

```
import arcpy

Var = str(input())

# Local variables:
Source = "D:\GIS\Source.shp"
Export = "D:\GIS\SHP"

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(Source, Export, "01_Export.shp", "\"Field\" = " + Var + ", "", "")
```

Could anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your Source.shp has a field named Field, instead of:

```
"\"Field\" = " + Var + "
```

try:

```
"Field = '{0}'".format(Var)
```

---

A two variables example syntax is:

```
"TextField = '{0}' AND NumField = {1}".format(Var1,Var2)
```

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo, it's work. One more question, how about if there are two or more variable that we will insert to query? For example "Field1 = Var1 AND Field2 = Var2"

Comment: @Dias that should be researched as a separate question.  If you need to, ask it as a new question, but I suspect there will be many earlier duplicates to choose from.

Comment: A two variables example syntax is: `"TextField = '{0}' AND NumField = {1}".format(Var,Var2)`